# How to 'DateTime of format specific' (The full date long time), like (Day/Month/Day/ yy:mm:tt AM)

Tags: c#, winforms

How to format to *Full date long time*? Full date long time is as follows: (Day/Month/Day/ yy:mm:tt AM) => **Monday 27 November 2023 06:08:00 PM**

I know several patterns. Things like `d`, `g`, `m`, `o`, `s`, `t`,
but there is no pattern I want among them.

Example

```cs
DateTime date = new DateTime(2023, 11, 27, 18, 08, 0);
Console.Write
(
    date.ToString('Specific Format here',
       CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
);

// Display
// Monday 27 November 2023 06:08:00 PM
```

Comment: please rephrase it is unclear what your question is, is the problem the different date ranges? what is the problem You experience??

Comment: ```GridView.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";``` use this  code to format the datetime for a column.

Comment: Another option is to format the date in your sql.  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mydate, "%W %M %e %Y") FROM Mytable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grid HTML

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateAndTime") %>'
```

Place "{0:M-dd-yyyy}"

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateAndTime", "{0:M-dd-yyyy}") %>'
```

Comment: The question is about WinForms, not about ASP.